# Wrong LAT/LNG returned by API

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps, coordinates

When I try to get lat/lng location based on an address the JSON return give wrong coordinates.

API Link: http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Av.+Major+Williams,+1132+Boa+Vista+RR+Brazil&sensor=false

JSON:

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "Boa Vista",
               "short_name" : "Boa Vista",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Boa Vista",
               "short_name" : "Boa Vista",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Roraima",
               "short_name" : "RR",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Brasil",
               "short_name" : "BR",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Boa Vista, Boa Vista - RR, Brasil",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 2.8686558,
                  "lng" : -60.6236814
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 2.7457422,
                  "lng" : -60.7694416
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 2.8235098,
               "lng" : -60.6758331
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 2.8686558,
                  "lng" : -60.6236814
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 2.7457422,
                  "lng" : -60.7694416
               }
            }
         },
         "partial_match" : true,
         "place_id" : "ChIJ26Sqy8oFk40RRV_XqcdlLrc",
         "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

If I set the address "Av. Major Williams, 1132 Boa Vista RR Brasil" on Google Maps the location is correct: lat 2.8291068, lng -60.6711494

Answer (score 0):

Your search is not resulting in a street address match using Geocoding. Your JSON shows that it found the smallest thing it could which was a locality.

Google maps does not search the same as Geocoding.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro